# Delphi DevExpress - SelectedRowCount on 2 level cxGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am working in Delphi 2006 using DevExpress.

I have an issue getting the SelectedRowCount from a cxGrid.
I have a master - detail setup and the master SelectedRowCount works fine but not the child table.
My MultiSelect option is set and I can visually select multiple records but the SelectedRowCount always comes back as 0.

Does anyone know if I am missing something?

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: There's several posts searching for "SelectedRowCount master detail" in de DevExpress support center at http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center

Comment: Thanks, I found a good link at devexpress.com with description "MultiSelect on GridView Level 2"  Thanks Jan